# coding an application in angularjs, i have an error of sintaxis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrimes/58wqH/) the code works

but when i try to pass this on my server i have an error

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

this is the js code

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function RegisterCtrl($scope, $location) 
{

  $scope.steps = [
    'Step 1: Team Info',
    'Step 2: Campaign Info',
    'Step 3: Campaign Media'
  ];
  $scope.selection = $scope.steps[0];

  $scope.getCurrentStepIndex = function()
  {
    // Get the index of the current step given selection
    return _.indexOf($scope.steps, $scope.selection);
  };

  // Go to a defined step index
  $scope.goToStep = function(index) 
  {
    if ( !_.isUndefined($scope.steps[index]) )
    {
      $scope.selection = $scope.steps[index];
    }
  };

  $scope.hasNextStep = function(){
    var stepIndex = $scope.getCurrentStepIndex();
    var nextStep = stepIndex + 1;
    // Return true if there is a next step, false if not
    return !_.isUndefined($scope.steps[nextStep]);
  };

  $scope.hasPreviousStep = function(){
    var stepIndex = $scope.getCurrentStepIndex();
    var previousStep = stepIndex - 1;
    // Return true if there is a next step, false if not
    return !_.isUndefined($scope.steps[previousStep]);
  };

  $scope.incrementStep = function() {
    if ( $scope.hasNextStep() )
    {
      var stepIndex = $scope.getCurrentStepIndex();
      var nextStep = stepIndex + 1;
      $scope.selection = $scope.steps[nextStep];
    }
  };

  $scope.decrementStep = function() {
    if ( $scope.hasPreviousStep() )
    {
      var stepIndex = $scope.getCurrentStepIndex();
      var previousStep = stepIndex - 1;
      $scope.selection = $scope.steps[previousStep];
    }
  };
}
```

what is the function of

```
$scope.goToStep = function(index) 
  {
    if ( !_.isUndefined($scope.steps[index]) )
    {
      $scope.selection = $scope.steps[index];
    }
  };
```

why is the error???

Comment: Have you referenced http://underscorejs.org/ in your html file?

Comment: why i need underscorejs??? give me the line of code that needs underscorejs}

Comment: every line where you have `_`. E.g. `_.indexOf` , `_.isUndefined` etc.

Comment: omg! i never use underscorejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the underscore library included in the head section of your html file, or if its a node app, as a module.

`<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>`

or if its server side code, do `npm install underscore` in your project root and then you can do

`var _ = require('underscore');`